# Is it possible to bevel a text mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers, text-object

Is it possible to apply a bevel to the edges of a text object after it has been converted to a mesh?
Less anyone be reticent to provide bad news, after looking at the topology, I'm doubtful myself.

This is what I'm doing:

1. Convert text to mesh
2. Using **Shrinkwrap** modifier, project the mesh-text onto the uneven surface of another mesh
3. Apply the modifier and extrude the text mesh.
   (Credit to a tutorial on youtube.)

The result looks pretty awesome for my skill level. (Easier for me than using curve modifiers.) But there appears to be no practical way to apply a bevel to the edges of the text.

Comment: Could you show screenshots of mesh in Edit mode ? Generally one of ways to get rid of bad topology on text objects is to retopologize them, one way is using **Shrinkwrap** modifier. What didn't work for you ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the workflow from the Text Object itself.

[image: How To Bevel Text]

Here's the workflow after Text has been converted to Mesh.

1. Use Limited Dissolve 1st. On the "Tool Shelf" You may need to slide the angle limit around. **Alternatively** on the delete menu, you can select **Dissolve Faces** directly, depending on the circumstance this may give you a more accurate dissolve for this purpose.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - With the Top Edges Selected to Bevel.

[image]

Comment: One note, Limited dissolve does not fix everything as it has its limitations. However it should get you most of the way to ideal (Look at my "e" character on the Left Side & my "t" where the cross member hits the stem). You may have to do some small retopo cleanup if this happens to leave edges in bad places, but this has got to be faster than going through the steps of shrinkwrapping.

Comment: The Limited Dissolve did the trick. Thanks. Just to be clear, I am using the shrinkwrap modifer to conform the text to uneven surfaces, not to fix topology. Thanks again